# How to correctly simplify indices in a generate for loop?

Tags: vhdl

So I wrote this piece of VHDL code that takes a 128 bit signal and swaps the byte positions of each 32/64-bit word (i.e. Big to Little Endian conversion).

As the indices are quite complex, I wanted to simplify it:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Test is
generic (DATA_WIDTH : integer := 32);
end Test;

architecture arch of Test is
signal test_in, test_simple, test_comp : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
begin


test_in <= x"01020304020202040303030404040405";

-- 128-bit signals: ReadyValid_RW_Port
GenReadyValid_RW_Port_Data:
for j in 128/DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0 generate
    -- for each of the 32/64 bit words, reverse the byte positions
    InnerLoop: 
    for i in DATA_WIDTH/8-1 downto 0 generate
    signal index : integer := (j * DATA_WIDTH/8 + i)*8;
    signal invindex : integer := ((j+1) * DATA_WIDTH/8 - 1 - i)*8;
    begin

        -- this way works, but looks messy
        test_comp((j * DATA_WIDTH/8 + i)*8+7 downto (j * DATA_WIDTH/8 + i)*8) <= 
            test_in(((j+1) * DATA_WIDTH/8 - 1 - i)*8+7 downto ((j+1) * DATA_WIDTH/8 - 1 - i)*8);

        -- simplify by writing the indices separately
        index <= (j * DATA_WIDTH/8 + i)*8;
        invindex <= ((j+1) * DATA_WIDTH/8 - 1 - i)*8;
        -- this doesnt work, test_simple stays U
        test_simple(index+7 downto index) <= test_in(invindex+7 downto invindex);
    end generate ;
end generate;

end architecture;
```

However in the Vivado Simulator,`test_simple` stays at value `U`, whereas `test_comp` works just fine. What is my mistake and how do you do correctly what I want to do?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your signals `index` and `invindex` are signals and hence create multiple drivers for the whole of `test_simple`. These should really be constants, not signals. `test_comp` slicing is using constants, and hence since I assume there is no overlap any indexing, the compiler can work out that each entry of `test_comp` only has a single driver.

Comment: This functionality is usually something that can be done inside a `function` rather than a generate.

Comment: Extended my code to a MCVE.  Thank you, the mistake was indeed declaring index and invindex as signals instead of as constants. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Tricky pointed out, the mistake was declaring `index` and `invindex` as signals instead of constants. With constants, it works perfectly fine:

```vhdl
-- 128-bit signals: ReadyValid_RW_Port
GenReadyValid_RW_Port_Data:
for j in 128/DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0 generate
    -- for each of the 32/64 bit words, reverse the byte positions
    InnerLoop: 
    for i in DATA_WIDTH/8-1 downto 0 generate
    constant index : integer := (j * DATA_WIDTH/8 + i)*8;
    constant invindex : integer := ((j+1) * DATA_WIDTH/8 - 1 - i)*8;
    begin

        test_simple(index+7 downto index) <= test_in(invindex+7 downto invindex);

    end generate ;
end generate;
```